# How can $X$ be a discrete random variable?

Tags: random-variable, density-function, cumulative-distribution-function, mixed-random-variable

> Suppose that the cumulative distribution function of discrete random variable $X$ is given by,
> $$F(x) =
> \begin{cases}
> 0  & \text{$x$ < 0 } \\[1.5ex]
> \dfrac{x}{4} & \text{$0 \leq x<1$}\\[1.5ex]
> \dfrac{1}{2}+\dfrac{x-1}{4} & \text{$1 \leq x<2$}\\[1.5ex]
> \dfrac{11}{12}   &\text{$2 \leq x<3$}\\[1.5ex]
> 1 &\text{$3 \leq x$}\\
> \end{cases}$$
> Find $P(X=i),i=1,2,3$.

How is it possible that $X$ be a discrete random variable as I think it is a mixed random variable (both discrete and continuous) since there are $x$ in $F(X)$.